# Should i use Regx,insert JQuery or HTML parsing on a WebView to get its content?

Tags: jquery, objective-c, uiwebview

**Acceptance creteria-ish**
I have a website (*not mine*) that i show in a WebView. Based on the content of the page i like to offer native button click (button not the issue).

**What needs to be done**
I need to check if the HTML content contains 2-3 certain urls. The url could be on 2-3 places on the page. If the urls aren´t there (sometimes they are, sometimes they aren´t) i need to do another search for content to create a url I´m going to fire up.

**Possible solutions**

1. *Screen scrape* using Objective-C-HMTL-Parser, HPPLE, ElemetParser, XPathQuery with libxml2 to parse the HTML and to search for the content. **Prons**: Easy ***Cons***: *Need a well formed HTML/XML. Probably slow for many concurrent searches down the tree.*
2. Use *regular expression*. **Prons**: ? **Cons**: *Gets hard to read/write fast. Need a well formed HTML/XML. Probably slow for many concurrent searches. (Haven´t tried* RegexKit Light).
3. *Insert JQuery* search functions into the WebView and call the functions from Objective-c. The [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge) looks promising to use to comunicate betweean Js and ObjC (also looked at TGJSBridge,GAJavaScript and iOS-JavaScript-Bridge  **Prons**: *Easy to inject the Jquery into the WebViewJavascriptBridge code and the call it using dele*  **Cons**: *Cumbersome*.
4. *Is there another solution I have missed?*

I´m leaning towards solution nr. 3. using [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge) where i would inject search JQuery functions into a handler that will get called when they find something. Could I run this search in multiple threads or search once down the tree and find all my search items?

**Recap**:

-1. What is the "best"/fastest solution searching for (multible) content in a web that is not your own?

-2. Is there another solution I have missed?

-3. Is it possible to run a multiple JQuery search in a thread, returning results back to Objc every single time something gets found?

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your question #2 (any other methods that you missed):

You could do parsing and all the other stuff, but just for looking if the HTML content contains certain URLs, wouldn't NSString's rangeOfString method suffice?
It depends on the formatting of the URL of course and what exactly you need (search for just any mention of the URL? Mention of the URL inside a certain tag? Could the URL appear elsewhere that shouldn't be regarded?).

But from your question I get that the task is a bit more complex, so could you provide a html snippet maybe?

Comment: Sorry for have taken this long to respond. I think that i will try the JQuery. NSString´s rangeOfString is to limited for my needs. I´m going to include the JQuery.js file to the project and inject it to the view and create 2-3 javascript (search) functions that i will also inject using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, witch i will also use to call the search function. Let me know if anyone needs to see this code!